# Spatie Laravel ActivityLog use with differences on update and on create

Tags: laravel, spatie-activitylog

I have a call to `getActivitylogOptions()` in a model.
But I need the data saved in the log to be different in the case of insert/update/delete.

For example, when inserting a new line, I only want to save one or two info fields. But in case of an update, I need to save all the fields that have been modified to know what exactly the user modified.

If I leave it like the following code, the update is correct, but when inserting, it saves all the fields which I don't need.

```
public function getActivitylogOptions(): LogOptions
{
    return LogOptions::defaults()
    ->logAll()
    ->logOnlyDirty();        
}
```

Is there any way to change the log according to the action?

Answer (score 1):

Hay, This is how i have it set and is only logging changes to properties that have been updated

```
public function getActivitylogOptions(): LogOptions
{
    return LogOptions::defaults()
        ->useLogName('Template_Model')
        ->logFillable()
        ->logOnlyDirty();
}
```